# Spring autowired bean creation

Tags: java, spring, ejb, vaadin, autowired

I have a Spring/Vaadin project and I am using RestTemplate to access external datasources, which are then filled into the vaadin components. The RestTemplate is autowired into my EJBs and these EJBs are injected into another spring components. How can I control, when are the spring beans going to be created?

For example: I have a menu structure and each menu entry has a clickListener which inserts the right component into the content part of the layout. This component is autowired and I can see in the logs, that it is created(thus the REST service is called) at the application start, and not upon the click event.

Another issue is, that all my Components that are being autowired cannot have contructors which operate on some autowired properties (I get NullPointerException) and therefore, the classes cannot be even instantiated in a usuall way. Can I somehow tell spring to autowire the fields first upon the object creation, i.e. so that the constructor method can work with the elements?

Answer (score 0):

The [`@Configurable` Annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) makes a object that is created by `new` a spring bean. -- Requires Aspect J